# Knuth-Pratt-Morris algorithm for real time

Tags: string, algorithm

[image]

From Additionally for real time search... can someone explain what it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a search term `aaaaaaaaaaaaa` and scan `aaaaaaaaaaaab`, then as soon as KMP scans the `b`, it will delete the partial match character by character, which takes time proportional to the match. By caching the transitions for each possible character, you can in essence build a deterministic finite automaton that processes each letter in worst-case constant time.